# Button Click from Annotation send object swift 4

Tags: ios, swift

I have inherited the annotations class in UIbutton like:

```
 class MapButton : UIButton{
         var clickedAnnotation : annotations? = nil
    }
```

Now, I am trying to read the properties of each annotation in annotations like this:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        if annotation is MKUserLocation {
            return nil
        }

        let reuseId = "pin"
        var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseId) as? MKPinAnnotationView
        if pinView == nil {
            pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)

            let colorPointAnnotation = annotation as! annotations
            pinView?.pinTintColor = colorPointAnnotation.pinColor

            let pinIsCurrentLocation = colorPointAnnotation.subtitle
            if pinIsCurrentLocation != "Current"
            {
            pinView?.canShowCallout = true
            }
            let smallSquare = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)
            let button = MapButton(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: smallSquare))
            button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "tasks"), for: .normal)
            button.clickedAnnotation = colorPointAnnotation
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MapController.TaskDetail(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            pinView?.leftCalloutAccessoryView = button
        }
        else {
            pinView?.annotation = annotation
        }

        return pinView
    }
```

But I am getting error "Type 'MapController' has no member 'TaskDetail'" in this line and unable to read properties in annotations.

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MapController.TaskDetail(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Button click method

```
func TaskDetail(_sender: MapButton){
        // Want to read the properties of each annotation when clicked on the map.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add `@objc` before `func TaskDetail(_sender: MapButton)` if you are using `Swift 4` and you have declared it within the class `MapController`.

for example

```
class MapController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

  func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        return nil
    }

    let reuseId = "pin"
    var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseId) as? MKPinAnnotationView
    if pinView == nil {
        pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)

        let colorPointAnnotation = annotation as! annotations
        pinView?.pinTintColor = colorPointAnnotation.pinColor

        let pinIsCurrentLocation = (colorPointAnnotation?.subtitle)!
        if pinIsCurrentLocation != "Current"
        {
            pinView?.canShowCallout = true
        }
        let smallSquare = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)
        let button = MapButton(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: smallSquare))
        button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "tasks"), for: .normal)
        button.clickedAnnotation = colorPointAnnotation
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(TaskDetail(_sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        pinView?.leftCalloutAccessoryView = button
    }
    else {
        pinView?.annotation = annotation
    }

    return pinView
  }

  @objc func TaskDetail(_sender: MapButton){
    // Want to read the properties of each annotation when clicked on the map.
  }
}
```

and you `MapButton` class

```
class MapButton : UIButton{
  var clickedAnnotation : annotations? = nil
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank for the reply @Dev_Bham, you are partly correct. The selector call must be like this, #selector(MapController.TaskDetail).